# jQuery $(document).on How to set stopPropagation() for dynamic a tag link click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, preventdefault, stoppropagation

Jquery dynamic created  link in the program.
It just like

```
<div>
...
<li><a class="page-list">aaa</a></li>
...
</div>
```

And we have defined the click function in Jquery lib.

Now I want to do stopPropagation for this click event in mousedown.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(document).on('mousedown', '.page-list', function(e){
                var $target = $(e.target);
                $target.off('click', stopClickEvent);
                if (window.confirm('Will run click event?')) {
                                $(this).click();
                }
                $target.on('click', stopClickEvent);
        }); 
});
function stopClickEvent(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

It doesn't work, when I click aaa, it still runs click event.

How to stopPropagation for a tag link in `$(document).on`?

If I set class="page-list" in li tag, it will work.

```
<li class="page-list"><a>aaa</a></li>
```

Comment: If I set  class="page-list" in <li> tag, it will work.<li class="page-list"><a>aaa</a></li>  WHY!!!!?????

Comment: Because the click event is attached to `.page-list`? So it will only work to elements with the `page-list` classname.

Comment: Yes, the click event is attached to .page-list.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mixups in your code:

First, you don't need this: `var $target = $(e.target);`, getting the target element should be as simple as `$(this)`, second you don't have to do `$target.off` and `$target.on` in order to stop event propagation, it has to be done inside the callback. Then, I think that the `click` handler runs because you explicitly call `click()` on `$(this)` which is the element itself.

So here's what I would do if I wanted to do something while stoping propagation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.page-list', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  // ... 
  alert('Element clicked"');
  // ...
});
```